# How to find the path to tf.exe from MsBuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-server

I have an MsBuild file which shells out to TFS using tf.exe for a few things. Unfortunately the tf.exe file has been installed to different locations on the developer PCs and the build server.

I could really do with a way of detecting where the tf.exe file is located within my script in the same way you can do $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) etc. Is this possible?

Thanks as always :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Does the environment variable VS100COMNTOOLS point to the correct path for visual studio?
E.g.
VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\

So then all you need is $(VS100COMNTOOLS)..\IDE

```
<Target Name="Build">
   <Exec Command="&quot;$(VS100COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\tf.exe&quot;"/>
</Target>
```

or however you want to tidy it up.

The  environment variable changes depending on the version of Visual Studio:

- `%VS110COMNTOOLS%` - Visual Studio 2012
- `%VS120COMNTOOLS%` - Visual Studio 2013
- `%VS140COMNTOOLS%` - Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Not sure what changed, but my tf.exe is not located in the Tools folder, but the IDE folder.

Comment: This is where mine is. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE

Comment: That's the path you get from the statement. Hence the ..\ide bit.

Comment: NB: As of VS2017 (at least, certain editions), this environment variable no longer exists by default, and https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/269.  However, you can create `VS150COMNTOOLS` by running: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/how-to-set-environment-variables-for-the-visual-studio-command-line

Answer (score 15):

Seems they changed location again in Visual Studio 2017.
It was not in any of the above locations on my machine.

I found TF.exe instead at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`

(Some users may find in the `Professional` folder instead of `Enterprise` folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe`)

Apparently [the environment variable is no longer set by default in VS 2017](http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/kb/48-vs2017).

Comment: Similarly, for me it was "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe" ... However, Rider says "the specified path does not lead to a valid TF executable"